# R bytecode reference in function code

Tags: r, function, bytecode

When examining the R code for a function, it lists a bytecode (for example, for glm): .
I've looked everywhere for a simple explanation for what "0x7f8f3c954540" actually is. I know what bytecode is, but I'm assuming "0x7f8f3c954540" isn't actually a highly compressed machine-processable version of the whole code for the glm function. Is it a CRC, a link to its location in memory, or the first few bits?

Answer (score 13):

If you look at the code in [print.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/52c467ea1c4493abe2d1e3483fd0658873a0c629/src/main/print.c#L205) in the R source, you can see that line is printed with

```
Rprintf("<bytecode: %p>\n", BODY(s));
```

This means it's printing the pointer address to the compiled version of the body of the function.

So the same function body code may point to two different addresses. Observe

```
f1<-function(a) {
    sum(runif(a) * 1/(1:a))
}
f2 <- f1
f1 <- compiler:::cmpfun(f1)
f2 <- compiler:::cmpfun(f2)
f3 <- f2

f1
# function(a) {
#       sum(runif(a) * 1/(1:a))
#    }
#<bytecode: 0x111cbb358>

f2
# function(a) {
#       sum(runif(a) * 1/(1:a))
#     }
# <bytecode: 0x111bd7800>

f3
#  function(a) {
#       sum(runif(a) * 1/(1:a))
#    }
#<bytecode: 0x111bd7800>
```

You can see that even though `f1` and `f2` have the same body code, they have different bytecode values. If you wanted to see if these two functions were identical you could use

```
identical(f1,f2)
# [1] TRUE
identical(f2,f3)
# [1] TRUE
```

but note the default is to ignore the compiled part of the function. If you wanted to see if they pointed to the same bytyecode as well

```
identical(f1,f2, ignore.bytecode=FALSE)
# [1] FALSE
identical(f2,f3, ignore.bytecode=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

So the bytecode value doesn't tell you anything about the code itself necessarily.